# Will running AsyncTask within AsyncTask cause memory leaks?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to send a http Post request every 5 seconds or so. For this I have set up an AsyncTask like this:

```
class httpPostAsync extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        httpPost();         //The posting function
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new httpPostAsync().execute();
            }
        },5000);
    }
}
```

I was wondering that if I use `execute()` inside the `onPostExecute()` function, wouldn't this cause multiple threads to form, since (I think) the previous thread hasn't ended before I am calling a new one. Or is this valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering that if I use execute() inside the onPostExecute() function (...)

Actually you are not executing anything in `onPostExecute()` - the only thing you do there is you add a new Runnable to the MessageQueue.

When system will take this message from the queue to process it, it will start the `run()` method from Runnable and it will add (`new httpPostAsync().execute();`) a new AsyncTask to the async tasks queue (because all async tasks are processed in separate single thread).

> (...) since (I think) the previous thread hasn't ended before I am calling a new one

You are mistaken again;) Only `doInBackground` method of AsyncTaks is run by the system on a separate worker thread. `onPostExecute` is run in Main UI thread of application and the `postDelay()` Runnable is executed in the same thread as `postDelay()` was, so in  your case - also in Main UI thread.

As far as I am concerned your code shouldn't cause memory leaks.

See:
[Android Developers - API Guides - Processes and Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I had always thought that every callback under AsyncTask ran on a non-UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not cause memory leaks.

But, you may want to rework how to are handling this. Spinning up an asynctask is expensive and you probably can use just one to accomplish this instead of chaining 2 of them.

for example,

```
void httpRequst()
void httpPost()

doInBackground(Void void){
   httpRequst();
   httpPost():
return null;
}
```

instead of launching a second async task...

Comment: Well, what I want is to call my method again and again asynchronously. So, I do not know the number of calls to be made beforehand and thus I cannot actually call two methods.

Comment: hmm perhaps a while loop will help? I really think you should restructure this code...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you declared httpPostAsync. For example if it's non-static inner class of Activity/Fragment it can lead to memory leaks.

If it's defined in a stand-alone file and you do not use context or members of Activity/Fragment all is fine.

Also you may consider to use Service.